# File writes stall during heavy disk I/O on Linux box

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, virtual-memory

I have two processes running on my box => A and B.

Whenever there is heavy disk I/O activity caused by writing large files to the disk by process A, I see that file writes in process B are stalling intermittently. I noticed that I had the following virtual memory settings on my linux kernel.

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 5  
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0  
vm.dirty_ratio = 20  
vm.dirty_bytes = 0  
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500  
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
```

Documentation states that 'dirty_background_ratio' is the percentage of the memory occupied by dirty pages before the kernel background flusher threads kick into action to flush the bytes to the disk. Given that I have 64 GB of memory, this background flush should kick off when the dirty page cache size reaches ~ 3.2 GB and I see that it is indeed the case when process A is writing to the disk.

However, as soon as this background flush starts, file writes in process B begin to stall intermittently for periods of about 10-20 seconds. ***Given that this disk flush is happening in the background, why does a write from process B stall given that all writes first go into the page cache and not directly to disk ?***

Comment: Do you have a hardware RAID controller with a write cache?

Comment: Running sudo /sbin/hdparm -I /dev/sda shows that write cache is enabled. Doing cat /proc/mdstat to check for RAID controller shows nothing.